# Is it safe to open an IDE HyperV VHDx as SCSI?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012

I adopted a HyperV environment and I'm trying to squeeze every bit of performance I can get out of it.

Some of the virtual machines in the environment have IDE drives instead of SCSI drives.

Is it safe to mount the VHDx as a SCSI drive?  Or do I need to convert it?

My alternative is to add a SCSI drive, boot up into knoppix, DD the IDE drive to the SCSI drive, then unmount the IDE drive.

Comment: Are any of these operating system drives?

Comment: Some are, some aren't.

Comment: For OS drives, boot from SCSI is relatively new for Hyper-V. It would need to be a Generation 2 VM, and Windows 8 x64/2012 or higher.

Comment: They are Windows Server 2008 and 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for conversion of the file - it's just like a physical disk with multiple interfaces.

You need to make sure the guest OS supports the SCSI drivers (which should be the case anyway) and may have to reattach the drive within the guest after changing it. As you're removing an IDE drive you've always to shutdown the guest before (detach of IDE is not allowed while the VM is running).

Comment: Ok, so, essentially, add a SCSI drive to it first so it has the SCSI drivers, then shut down, then unmount the IDE drives, then remount the VHDx files as SCSI drives, and boot up?

Comment: When running a microsoft guest OS the drivers are always installed - same for linux (at least current versions contain the hyperv components in the kernel). 
When booting the vm first time after changing the bus you will need to restore the mount points of the disk - but that shouldn't be a big deal.